# React App - How to change IP address when running locally?

Tags: reactjs

I'm running a react app locally. It seems to be running fine except my IP address is wrong:

[image]

How can I change this to localhost:3000 or something similar?

Comment: Just to check: your machine is **not** called `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0` ? The URL given is wrong? Or is it just not what you expected?

Comment: my machine is called `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0`. However, all the other SO threads I've referenced tell me the app should be running on localhost:3000 or 127.0.0.1:3000 or something similar

Comment: It might be useful to add the command line you used to produce that output. Also, post text as text instead of images. You can't copy-past part of an image into a search engine.